# Identify the error in approach in calculating maximum number of flags that can be set on mountain peaks?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve the latest codility.com question (just for enhance my skills). I tried allot but only passing with 33%.

**The question says**

> A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. A
>   peak is an array element which is larger than its neighbours. More
>   precisely, it is an index P such that 
>       0 < P < N − 1 and A[P − 1] < A[P] > A[P + 1]
>
> For example, the following array A: `{1,5,3,4,3,4,1,2,3,4,6,2}`; has
>   exactly four peaks: elements 1, 3, 5 and 10.
>
> You are going on a trip to a range of mountains whose relative heights
>   are represented by array A. You have to choose how many flags you
>   should take with you. The goal is to set the maximum number of flags
>   on the peaks, according to certain rules.
>
> Flags can only be set on peaks. What's more, if you take K flags, then
>   the distance between any two flags should be greater than or equal to
>   K. The distance between indices P and Q is the absolute value |P − Q|.
>
> For example, given the mountain range represented by array A, above,
>   with N = 12, if you take:
>
> > two flags, you can set them on peaks 1 and 5;
> >     three flags, you can set them on peaks 1, 5 and 10;
> >     four flags, you can set only three flags, on peaks 1, 5 and 10. You can therefore set a maximum of three flags in this case.
>
> Write a function that, given a non-empty zero-indexed array A of N
>   integers, returns the maximum number of flags that can be set on the
>   peaks of the array. For example, given the array above the function
>   should return 3, as explained above.
>
> Assume that: N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each
>   element of array A is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000].
>
> Complexity: expected worst-case time complexity is O(N); expected
>   worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not
>   counting the storage required for input arguments).

My approach:

1. Find the number of peaks and store it in another array.
2. Start from index [1]  and try to find the maximum flags we can put based on the given condition
3. Start from backwards and try to find the maximum flags we can put based on the given condition
4. Maximum of the numbers calculated in step 2 and 3 will be the answer.

Could somebody point me to the error in my solution https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingWH3FGA-ZNN/

```
public static int countFlagOnPeaks(int[] a){
        int totalFlagFront = 0, countPeaks = 0,totalFlagBack = 0;
        int b[] = new int[a.length];
        int totalFlag= 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
            if(a[i] > a[i-1] && a[i] > a[i+1]) {
                countPeaks++;
                b[i] = 1;
            }
        }
        int lastPeak = -1;
        for (int i = 1; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
            if(b[i] == 1 && lastPeak == -1) {
                totalFlagFront++;
                lastPeak = i;
            }
            if(b[i] == 1 && i-lastPeak >= countPeaks) {
                    totalFlagFront++;
                    lastPeak = i;
            }
        }

        lastPeak = -1;
        for (int i = b.length-2; i > 0; i--) {
            if(b[i] == 1 && lastPeak == -1) {
                lastPeak = i;
                totalFlagBack++;
            }
            if(b[i] == 1 && lastPeak-i >= countPeaks) {
                    totalFlagBack++;
                    lastPeak = i;
            }
        }
        totalFlag = Math.max(totalFlagBack, totalFlagFront);
        return totalFlag;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  Your posted code merely defines a routine and exits without executing anything.

Comment: I'm not sure that either 2. or 3. is the ultimate solution. You start from one end of array and set flags to satisfy the condition. How does that guarantee the optimum? Maybe you could get a better solution if you skip one of the peaks? Or if you don't start from the first peak? That's really not obvious and I'm not sure it is correct.

Comment: We can't easily follow your (non-)algorithm or code.  Your "approach" has a large contingent of "magic" in the phrase "try to find the maximum".  Your code lacks comments and contains a large proportion of meaningless variable names.  Make it easy for us, and you'll get much better help.

Comment: Finally, you've neglected to give us the incorrect results with which you want help.

Comment: I would eliminate `countPeaks` and change `int[] b = new int[a.length];` to `List<int> b = new ArrayList<>();` then when you find a peak, store its index. Also your peak finding code precludes the first and last indexes from being peaks, I'm not sure if that is a problem.

Comment: After finding the peaks into a `List`, you could create a new `List` that has just the distances between each peak. Then it should be a simple matter to find the largest number that has the most distances greater than it and add one.

Comment: I think this is a question for codereview or codegolf